# Hot observable error handling

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs5

I have an observable, that listens for the `keyup` event from an `input.

On every `keyup`, it makes a request to the server and if there aren't any values, it will throw an exception.

```
.map(function (oResp) {
  if (oResp.data.results.length === 0) {
    throw new Error(self.getTextBundle("insPlantInvalid"));
  } 
  return oResp.data.results;
})
```

After the exception was thrown, the observable is not going to listen for the event anymore.

Does the exception handling in `rxjs` work in this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is correct behavior. Exception makes the [operator send an `error`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/operator/map.ts#L74) notification. Both `error` or `complete` signals have to be the last signals emitted and both also [cause unsubscription](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/Subscriber.ts#L138).

To resubscribe or handle errors there are operators such as `retry()`, `retryWhen()`, `catch()` or `onErrorResumeNext()`. I guess you already know these.

Comment: I tried it with `catch()` and the stream will unsubscribed too after that?

Comment: @zero_coding You tried what with `catch()`? With `catch()` you can subscribe to another Observable instead of the source.

Comment: In my case, when the user typed an invalid value into the input field, it will mark the input field with red color. So when the user type a valid value, the red color will be deleted. It is better to resolve with `retryWhen()`?

Comment: I used `catch()` and return the source observable, as long as the user type a valid value.

Answer (score 0):

`.catch()` can also be used to handle error.

```
this.http.get('url').map(res => res.json()).catch(() => Observable.of({error: true})
```

This is return `{error: true}` in case of error and the event observable wont break. But in the map operator which comes next to this response needs to handle this case.